Applying Shapley values to classification
According to the definition by Štrumbelj and Kononenko (2013), Shapley values are defined for regression predictions.
They should, however, also be applicable to classifications when the classifier not only yields a class, but class probabilities $P(\omega_i|x)$. The problem is that this yields $C$ Shapley values for each feature, where $C$ is the number of possible classes $\omega_i$.
Question: Is there a way to combine these values into a single value per feature that represents the contribution of this feature to the decision?
Example in R: A simple Gaussian Bayes classifier, also known as "quadratic discriminant analysis for the iris dataset, with the Shapley values estimated by Kernel SHAP (which assumes independence of the features):
library(MASS)
library(kernelshap)

# overwrite predict to return the class probabilities
mypredict <- function(model, ...) {
  res <- MASS:::predict.qda(model, ...)
  return(res$posterior)
}

model <- qda(Species ~ ., iris)
s <- kernelshap(model, iris[,-5], pred_fun=mypredict)

# Shapley values for first iris sample
print(lapply(s$S, function(x) {x[1,]}))

which returns
$setosa
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
 -0.01393733   0.01488391   0.43523643   0.23048366 

$versicolor
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
 -0.02314857   0.01283692  -0.14713220  -0.16850077 

$virginica
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
 0.03708591  -0.02772083  -0.28810423  -0.06198289 


One reasonable way to do so would be to adjust the outcome metric from predicted probabilities to a metric that collapses across the categories like an accuracy metric as implemented by yardstick::accuracy_vec() and pull the method through a function that can work with that single value as output.
Not sure of whether kernelshap can accommodate yardstick::accuracy_vec() but domir::domir() can.  This method produces a non-approximate (i.e., doesn't assume independent features) but suffers from the scalability issues that led to methods like kernelshap in the first place. For this toy problem, it works well however.
For example using:
library(MASS)
library(domir)
library(yardstick)

model <- qda(Species ~ ., iris)

yardstick::accuracy_vec(iris$Species, predict(model)$class)

produces the following accuracy value:
[1] 0.98

That model can be pulled through domir() with some adjustments to get it to work with MASS::qda() as below.
domir(
  reformulate(names(iris)[-5], response = "Species"),
  \(fml) {
    name_list <- attr(terms(fml), "term.labels")
    x <- 
      iris[,name_list] |> 
      as.matrix()
    qda(x, iris$Species) |>
      predict() |>
      _[["class"]] |>
      accuracy_vec(iris$Species)
  }, .cpt = FALSE, .cdl = FALSE
)

Which produces:
Overall Value:      0.98 

General Dominance Values:
             General Dominance Standardized Ranks
Sepal.Length         0.2050000    0.2091837     3
Sepal.Width          0.1416667    0.1445578     4
Petal.Length         0.3127778    0.3191610     2
Petal.Width          0.3205556    0.3270975     1

A decomposition of the accuracy metric for each feature collapsing across outcome categories.
As mentioned above, the domir() method is not designed for scalability and may not perform well on large-scale Shapley value decomposition problems. Rather it is designed for breadth of applicability to (mostly linear) models following model selection.

Yes, it is possible to collapse the predictions to a resubstitution recognition rate, but using this as a criterion, e.g. for dominance analysis, will only yield global values for feature importance, not local values for each prediction. Nevertheless, thanks for the pointer to domir which estimates feature importanc by retraining and thus does not rely on a feature independence assumption like SHAP.

The suggestion by jluchman to use the (resubstitution) recognition rate as a criterion for dominance analysis computes how much adding each feature changes the recognition rate averaged over all feature subsets. This can be used as a global measure for feature importance, but does not yield information how much each feature contributes to the individual decisions.
It seems to me that a simple method to compute SHAP values for classification problems is to compute it for the probability of all classes, and only pick the SHAP values from the class for which the decision (in presence of all features) was made. This summarizes how much the features contributed to increasing the probability of this class.
I have not found a way to feed this reduced result into the visualization functions of the package shapviz, but it is easy to visualize with the beeswarm package for base R graphics:
class <- predict(model, iris)$class
S <- s$S[[1]]
for (i in 1:nrow(iris)) {
  S[i,] <- s$S[[as.character(class.char[i])]][i,]
}
beeswarm(as.data.frame(S), method="center",
         pwcol=rep(as.integer(class),ncol(S)))
legend("topleft", levels(class), pch=1, col=1:length(levels(class)))


Global feature importance can also be computed by averaging over all samples:
> colMeans(abs(S))
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
  0.02872648   0.02413223   0.33380242   0.30245001 

This differs form the domir result, though, because it uses a different evaluation criterion (probability versus recognition rate), and the features are highly correlated so that the independence assumption by kernelshap is not justified. Nevertheless, the overall tendencies are the same.
